# How to assign existing code/bitmaps to MFC

Tags: c++, windows, mfc, dice

So I wrote a program that simulates a dice game, almost like the game of Craps. I want to turn this normal console app into a dialogue based MFC. So I would create a button labeled "Roll" and the window would show two die being rolled.
Here is the code I have for the condole app. It works perfectly, but I am so confused as to how to assign the code to the button and also how to assign the die faces to its respective bitmaps. I appreciate the help!

```
//Game of chance "Craps"

#include "stdafx.h"
using namespace std;

void dice(void)
{
    //variables
    string  input;
    int     i,roll,gamePoint,val,val_1,val_2,roll_1,roll_2,sumRoll;
    long    winnings,losses,wager,odds,oddsNumer,oddsDenom;
    bool    A=false;
    //declarations
    roll=0;gamePoint=0;val=0;val_1=0;val_2=0;roll_1=0;roll_2=0;sumRoll=0;
    //user input
    cout<<"Enter your odds ratio:\nNumerator: ";
    cin>>oddsNumer;
    cout<<setw(8)<<"Denominator: ";
    cin>>oddsDenom;
    cout<<"Enter your wager for the game: ";
    cin>>wager;
    odds=abs((oddsNumer/oddsDenom)+1);
    winnings=abs(odds*wager-wager);
    cout<<winnings;
    //dice output
    do
    {
        srand (unsigned(time(NULL)));
        sumRoll=0;
        for(i=0;i<2;i++)
        {
            val_1=rollDice();
            //cout<<"***test1***";
            switch (val_1)
            {//start switch
                case 1:
                    dieFace(val_1);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    dieFace(val_1);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    dieFace(val_1);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    dieFace(val_1);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    dieFace(val_1);
                    break;
                case 6:
                    dieFace(val_1);
                    break;
            }//end switch
            sumRoll=val_1+sumRoll;
        }//end for loop dice roll
        cout<<endl<<endl<<"\tYou rolled a: "<<sumRoll<<endl;
        system("pause");
        if (sumRoll==7 ||sumRoll==11)
        {
            cout<<"Hurray! You win!\n"<<
            "Your total winnings: $"<<winnings<<endl;
            A=true;
            system("pause");
        }//and if winner statement
        else if(sumRoll==2 ||sumRoll==3||sumRoll==12)
        {
            losses=abs(odds*wager);
            cout<<"Sorry, you lose. The house wins. Total lost is $"<<
            losses<<endl;
            A=true;
            system("pause");
        }
        else
        {

            gamePoint=sumRoll;
            roll=0;

            do
            {
                srand (unsigned(time(NULL)));
                sumRoll=0;
                roll++;
                for(i=0;i<2;i++)
                {
                    val_1=rollDice();

                    switch (val_1)
                    {//start switch
                        case 1:
                            dieFace(val_1);
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            dieFace(val_1);
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            dieFace(val_1);
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            dieFace(val_1);
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            dieFace(val_1);
                            break;
                        case 6:
                            dieFace(val_1);
                            break;
                    }//end switch
                    sumRoll=val_1+sumRoll;
                }//end for loop dice roll
                cout<<endl<<endl<<"\tYou rolled a: "<<sumRoll<<endl;
                system("pause");
                if (sumRoll==7)
                {
                    losses=abs(wager*roll*odds);
                    cout<<"Sorry, you lose. The house wins."<<
                    "Total lost is $"<<losses<<endl;
                    A=true;
                    system("pause");
                }
                else if(sumRoll==gamePoint)
                {
                    winnings=abs(wager*roll*odds-wager);
                    cout<<"Hurray! You win!\n"<<
                    "Your total winnings are $"<<winnings<<endl;
                    A=true;
                    system("pause");
                }
            }while(A==false);
        }
    }while(A==false);
    system("pause");
    system("cls");
    return ;
}

int rollDice(void)
{
    //srand (unsigned(time(0)));
    return((rand()%6)+1);
}
void dieFace(int val)
{

    switch (val)
    {//start switch
        case 1:
            cout<<endl<<endl<<endl;
            cout<<"     *************"<<endl;
            cout<<"     *           *"<<endl;
            cout<<"     *           *"<<endl;
            cout<<"     *     O     *"<<endl;
            cout<<"     *           *"<<endl;
            cout<<"     *           *"<<endl;
            cout<<"     *************"<<endl<<endl;

            break;
        case 2:
            cout<<endl<<endl<<endl;
            cout<<"     *************"<<endl;
            cout<<"     *         O *"<<endl;
            cout<<"     *           *"<<endl;
            cout<<"     *           *"<<endl;
            cout<<"     *           *"<<endl;
            cout<<"     * O         *"<<endl;
            cout<<"     *************"<<endl<<endl;

            break;
        case 3:
            cout<<endl<<endl<<endl;
            cout<<"     *************"<<endl;
            cout<<"     *         O *"<<endl;
            cout<<"     *           *"<<endl;
            cout<<"     *     O     *"<<endl;
            cout<<"     *           *"<<endl;
            cout<<"     * O         *"<<endl;
            cout<<"     *************"<<endl<<endl;

            break;
        case 4:
            cout<<endl<<endl<<endl;
            cout<<"     *************"<<endl;
            cout<<"     * O       O *"<<endl;
            cout<<"     *           *"<<endl;
            cout<<"     *           *"<<endl;
            cout<<"     *           *"<<endl;
            cout<<"     * O       O *"<<endl;
            cout<<"     *************"<<endl<<endl;

            break;  
        case 5:
            cout<<endl<<endl<<endl;
            cout<<"     *************"<<endl;
            cout<<"     * O       O *"<<endl;
            cout<<"     *           *"<<endl;
            cout<<"     *     O     *"<<endl;
            cout<<"     *           *"<<endl;
            cout<<"     * O       O *"<<endl;
            cout<<"     *************"<<endl<<endl;

            break;
        case 6:
            cout<<endl<<endl<<endl;
            cout<<"     *************"<<endl;
            cout<<"     * O       O *"<<endl;
            cout<<"     *           *"<<endl;
            cout<<"     * O       O *"<<endl;
            cout<<"     *           *"<<endl;
            cout<<"     * O       O *"<<endl;
            cout<<"     *************"<<endl<<endl;

            break;
    }
    return  ;
}
```

Comment: Do you own, or have access to *any* books on programming windows with MFC? ["Programming Windows with MFC"](http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Windows-MFC-Second-Edition/dp/1572316950) is a decent one.

Comment: You should tackle one problem at a time. Get the commadn handler added for the button and use static controls to display the results or activity. Once that's done move on to adding the bitmaps. Asking about both will just make it harder to provide a working solution. I suggest you pick which one is more important and update your question to focus on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an event handler to process mouse clicks for the button control. Let's say you have added a button to the dialog and given it the resource id `IDC_ROLLDICE`. To add an event handler right click on the button you added and select "Add event handler". A window will pop up asking to you fill in a bit of information.  Under "Message type" make sure that `BN_CLICKED` is selected. This will tell the MFC message dispatcher that you are interested in that specific event. Give it a name in the field labeled "Function handler name". Once you have all of that information added click "Add and Edit". This will add a member function to your CDialog derived class and an entry in the message map to make sure it gets called. It should look something like below

```
void CMyDialog::OnBnClickedRolldice()
{
// TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
}
```

Now, whenever you click the button MFC will call `OnBnClickedRolldice`. Just start adding your code to roll the dice into that member function and add member variables as needed.

Basically you will move your entire application into the CDialog derived class via member variables and functions.